# Input transition time of 74HC4046

Tags: pll

In 74HC4046's [datasheet](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC_HCT4046A_CNV.pdf), section "Recommended operating conditions", i find this

[image]

1. I wonder if this is only applied to pin 5 - INH, the VCO eanble/disable pin?
2. Does \$SIG_{IN}\$ pin have any similar input transition time limitation? In my opinion, CMOS devices such as 74HC/HCT series usually have input transition time limitation. Such as TI's HC/HCT series, when \$V_{CC}=4.5V\$, the maximum input transition time is 500ns.

---

**Update:**

In a very old chip - CD4046B's [datasheet](http://www.ti.com.cn/cn/lit/ds/symlink/cd4046b.pdf), i find this:

[image]

For SIGin pin, it gives two limitations:

1. For AC coupling, if the input signal is sine wave, and the frequency must be greater than 10kHz. And at 100kHz sine wave input, the minimum sensitivity is 360mV (max.).
2. It also gives the rising/falling time limitation for signal pin when using phase comp. II, i thought this is for DC coupled signal.

I want to know, in AC coupling signal, for sine wave, why it limits the frequency? Does it have any relation with transition time? And for 74HC4046, when it gives the AC coupled input sensitivity, it also gives the test condition: \$t_{r} = t_{f}\$, if my AC coupled signal has a different rising\falling time, then what's the minimum peak-peak value of my signal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, when you have minimum edge rates specified it is because that signal is interacting with an internal clock or signal in a way that might generate dangerous signals.  Looking at the data-sheet the INH (Inhibit) pin goes directly into the VCO, which probably means that a slow slewing INH input would cause runt pulses, for example.  You'd need more detail to be sure.

The SIGin input goes to a buffer , so presumably that will shape things up nicely for subsequent processing.

In general if the data-sheet mentions something, you should follow it.  If it does, then you can ignore it.  Especially in such an old design, like this part.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm now working on a design, like this:http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/137291/pll-low-frequency-synthesis-with-74hct9046a. I know this is a "old" part, can your suggest a newer one suited for me. And i have some more doubts and have updated the question.